Android custom native dialer with ConnectionService implementation for OutgoingCall never goes out
I am trying to implement ConnectionService, Connection, and registering  PhoneAccount for outgoing calls. So far, I have been able to initiate a call using customPhoneAccount but that phone call never goes through, which means the call does not reach the destination phone.
Below is code for PhoneAccount and ConnectionService,
@RequiresApi(api = Build.VERSION_CODES.M)
    private void registerConnectionService() {
        try {
            TelecomManager manager = (TelecomManager) getSystemService(Context.TELECOM_SERVICE);
            String connectionServiceId = getConnectionServiceId();
            ComponentName componentName = new ComponentName(getApplicationContext(), MyService.class);
            PhoneAccountHandle phoneAccountHandle = new PhoneAccountHandle(componentName, "Dialer");
            phoneAccount = manager.getPhoneAccount(phoneAccountHandle);
            // Log.i("phoneAccountTekV",phoneAccount.getAddress()+" "+phoneAccount.getCapabilities()+"  "+phoneAccount.getLabel());
            if (phoneAccount == null) { // no phone account from us registered yet
                PhoneAccount.Builder builder = PhoneAccount.builder(phoneAccountHandle, "Dialer");
                Uri uri = Uri.parse("tel:123456789");
                //builder.setSubscriptionAddress(uri);
                //builder.setAddress(uri);
                builder.setCapabilities(PhoneAccount.CAPABILITY_CALL_PROVIDER);
               
                phoneAccount = builder.build();
                manager.registerPhoneAccount(phoneAccount);
                Log.i("phoneAccount", "" + phoneAccount.isEnabled());
                Intent intent = new Intent();
                intent.setComponent(new ComponentName("com.android.server.telecom",
                        "com.android.server.telecom.settings.EnableAccountPreferenceActivity"));
                startActivity(intent);
            }
            Log.i("is phoneAccountEnabled", "" + phoneAccount.isEnabled());
        } catch (SecurityException se) {
            Log.e("registerPhoneAccount", "SecurityException: Ensure all necessary permissions are granted", se);
        } catch (IllegalArgumentException iae) {
            Log.e("registerPhoneAccount", "IllegalArgumentException: Ensure the PhoneAccount is properly configured", iae);
        } catch (RuntimeException re) {
            Log.e("registerPhoneAccount", "RuntimeException: An unexpected error occurred", re);
        } catch (Exception re) {
            Log.e("registerPhoneAccount", "Exception: An unexpected error occurred", re);
        }
    }

ConnectionService:
@RequiresApi(api = Build.VERSION_CODES.Q)
    @RequiresPermission(value = "android.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE")
    @Override
    public Connection onCreateOutgoingConnection(PhoneAccountHandle connectionManagerPhoneAccount, ConnectionRequest originalRequest) {
        Uri handle = originalRequest.getAddress();
        MyConnection connection = new MyConnection(false, originalRequest,this);
        connection.setAddress(handle, TelecomManager.PRESENTATION_ALLOWED);
        //connection.setConnectionProperties(Connection.PROPERTY_SELF_MANAGED);
       // connection.setDialing();
        connection.setInitializing();
        connection.setConnectionCapabilities(Connection.CAPABILITY_HOLD | Connection.CAPABILITY_MUTE | Connection.CAPABILITY_SUPPORT_HOLD);
        connection.setVideoState(originalRequest.getVideoState());
        addCall(connection);
        TelecomManager manager = (TelecomManager) getSystemService(Context.TELECOM_SERVICE);
        boolean isOut = manager.isOutgoingCallPermitted(connectionManagerPhoneAccount);
        Log.i("phoneAccountTekV",connectionManagerPhoneAccount.getUserHandle().toString());
                //setAddress(connection,handle);
        Log.i("isOutgoingCallPermitted"," isOutgoingCallPermitted-"+isOut);
        PhoneAccountHandle ph = manager.getUserSelectedOutgoingPhoneAccount();
        List<PhoneAccountHandle>  selfHandles =manager.getSelfManagedPhoneAccounts();
        List<PhoneAccountHandle>  handles =manager.getCallCapablePhoneAccounts();
        connection.startOutgoing();
        return connection;

    }

Logs from LogCat is below:
12:27:49.085 1563-1563/? W/Telecom: Call: maybeOnInCallServiceTrackingChanged() request on a call without a connection service.: ICSBC.oSC(cgag)@C/U
2024-06-24 12:27:49.085 1563-1563/? W/Telecom: Call: maybeOnInCallServiceTrackingChanged() request on a call without a connection service.: ICSBC.oSC(cgaa)@C/Y
2024-06-24 12:27:49.091 1563-6781/? W/WindowManager: Prepare app transition: mNextAppTransitionRequests=[TRANSIT_OPEN, TRANSIT_OPEN], mNextAppTransitionFlags=, displayId: 0 Callers=com.android.server.wm.DisplayContent.prepareAppTransition:6493 com.android.server.wm.TaskFragment.resumeTopActivity:1573 com.android.server.wm.TaskFragment.resumeTopActivity:1307 com.android.server.wm.Task.resumeTopActivityInnerLocked:6451 com.android.server.wm.Task.resumeTopActivityUncheckedLocked:6352
2024-06-24 12:27:49.091 1563-6781/? W/ActivityTaskManager: Tried to set launchTime (0) < mLastActivityLaunchTime (1105139)
2024-06-24 12:27:49.096 1563-1563/? W/Telecom: Call: maybeOnInCallServiceTrackingChanged() request on a call without a connection service.: TSI.pC->CM.fOCP->CM.sOCPA->CM.dSMCP->CM.dSPA->CM.sRCQ->CM.pASP(ctd)@C/M
2024-06-24 12:27:49.096 1563-1563/? W/Telecom: Call: maybeOnInCallServiceTrackingChanged() request on a call without a connection service.: TSI.pC->CM.fOCP->CM.sOCPA->CM.dSMCP->CM.dSPA->CM.sRCQ->CM.pASP(ctd)@C/M
2024-06-24 12:27:49.097 1563-6781/? W/WindowManager: Execute app transition: mNextAppTransitionRequests=[TRANSIT_OPEN, TRANSIT_OPEN], mNextAppTransitionFlags=, displayId: 0 Callers=com.android.server.wm.RootWindowContainer.executeAppTransitionForAllDisplay:2580 com.android.server.wm.ActivityTaskSupervisor.reportResumedActivityLocked:2287 com.android.server.wm.ActivityRecord.completeResumeLocked:6987 com.android.server.wm.Task.minimalResumeActivityLocked:6156 com.android.server.wm.ActivityTaskSupervisor.realStartActivityLocked:1137
2024-06-24 12:27:49.098 1563-1563/? W/Telecom: Call: maybeOnInCallServiceTrackingChanged() request on a call without a connection service.: TSI.pC->CM.fOCP->CM.sOCPA->CM.dSMCP->CM.dSPA->CM.sRCQ->CM.pASP(ctd)@C/M
2024-06-24 12:27:49.099 1224-1461/? W/SecAudioParamPolicy: g_volume_situation_key: did not support legacy situation volumes
2024-06-24 12:27:49.099 32494-32494/? E/m.samsung.crane: Not starting debugger since process cannot load the jdwp agent.
2024-06-24 12:27:49.102 9896-9925/? E/BluetoothAdapterService: getActiveDevices: HearingAidService is null
2024-06-24 12:27:49.107 1563-1563/? W/Telecom: Logging: Log.endSession was called with no session active.
2024-06-24 12:27:49.110 9896-9925/? E/BluetoothAdapterService: getActiveDevices: HearingAidService is null
W/ContextImpl: Calling a method in the system process without a qualified user: android.app.ContextImpl.sendBroadcast:1252 com.android.server.notification.sec.DisplayToast.sendIntentForToastDumpLog:156 com.android.server.notification.sec.DisplayToast.outFile:106 com.android.server.notification.sec.DisplayToast.out:62 com.android.server.notification.NotificationManagerService$12.enqueueToastForDex:3989
2024-06-24 12:27:49.507 5214-5307/? W/Parcel: Expecting binder but got null!
2024-06-24 12:27:49.513 677-677/? W/keymaster_tee: [WRN]begin req PARAMS: A32 B32 P1
2024-06-24 12:27:49.521 677-677/? W/keymaster_tee: [WRN]begin req PARAMS: A32 B32 P1
2024-06-24 12:27:49.529 1121-1121/? E/Sensors: inject_scontext_data: New ssp_data_injection_fd(44)
2024-06-24 12:27:49.530 1563-1718/? W/BroadcastQueue: Background execution not allowed: receiving Intent { act=com.samsung.rcs.contentsharing.action.NUMBER_TOKEN flg=0x10 (has extras) } to com.samsung.crane/.app.PhoneNumberReceiver
2024-06-24 12:27:49.536 1563-1718/? W/BroadcastQueue: Permission Denial: receiving Intent { act=android.intent.action.PHONE_STATE flg=0x1000010 (has extras) } to ProcessRecord{b77a6ce 6726:com.samsung.android.app.cocktailbarservice/u0a52} (pid=6726, uid=10052) requires android.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE due to sender android (uid 1000)
2024-06-24 12:27:49.537 1563-1718/? W/BroadcastQueue: Permission Denial: receiving Intent { act=android.intent.action.PHONE_STATE flg=0x1000010 (has extras) } to ProcessRecord{b77a6ce 6726:com.samsung.android.app.cocktailbarservice/u0a52} (pid=6726, uid=10052) requires android.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE due to sender android (uid 1000)
2024-06-24 12:27:49.537 9896-18745/? E/BluetoothAdapterService: getActiveDevices: HearingAidService is null
can someone please help me ?

I am new to Android. I need help for solving above issue. Please suggest me solution if you know, why giving downvote?
I need to implement default dialer replacement with basic call and conference support. can someone suggest me to solve?

Implemented native dialer without Custom ConnectonService. For native dialer that should replace the default dialer of Androind is not solved by our custom ConnectionService due to a lack of system permissions.
The solution is our custom dialer app should use system's default ConnectionService Implementation TelephonyConnectionService.
Now I can do below,

Basic Calls (incoming and outgoing, Answer, Reject Call, Cancel Call, Disconnect),
Hold/resume
Conference  (Add Call and Merge)

We can implement whatever the default phone app supports.

This answer is not clear and correct. Please provide more clear answer with some examples of code/snippet or any other GitHub project would be acceptable.
